# Weird stuff happening when moving objects from one YAML list to other

Tags: java, yaml, bukkit

I have a problem regarding YAML files.
When I try moving objects from one list to another inside of a .yml file and save it, weird stuff like this happens:

```
queued: &id001 []
current: *id001
```

What's supposed to happen:

```
current: Fraithor # <= Minecraft username, from queued, moved when running reQueue()
queued: [] # <= Or just nothing / delete list
```

reQueue() method:

```
        for (String path : FileBasics.FILETYPE.BANWAVE.getConfig().getStringList("queued")) {

            List<String> list = FileBasics.FILETYPE.BANWAVE.getConfig().getStringList("current");
            List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            arrayList.add(path);

            list.addAll(arrayList);
            FileBasics.FILETYPE.BANWAVE.getConfig().set("current", list);
            list.remove(path);
            FileBasics.FILETYPE.BANWAVE.getConfig().set("queued", list);
            try {
                FileBasics.FILETYPE.BANWAVE.getConfig().save(FileBasics.FILETYPE.BANWAVE.getFile());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Obviously, I'm using a seperate class/emnum for the File saving (FileBasics). It's a pretty long code, so I pasted it on pastebin [HERE](https://pastebin.com/XsqvYTBb) (https://pastebin.com/XsqvYTBb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing the same list to both `current` and `queued`. Java has reference semantics meaning that if you push `arrayList` to `current`, `current` holds a *reference* to `arrayList` so if you alter it, `current` will point to the altered list.

Since you push the very same list to `queued`, YAML will add an anchor `&id001` when the list first occurs, and an alias `*id001` to refer to the same list afterwards.

Since you don't want a list in `current` at all, it seems you want to do

```java
FileBasics.FILETYPE.BANWAVE.getConfig().set("current", path);
```

Though I have no idea what kind of API this is and whether it accepts a string.